# Grouping similar items using xsl 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to group the records based on OPERATION_CODE. Each record can have more than one Allowance in combination tag. If more than one record have same operation_code, I need all the allowance together. I am using xsl 1.0.
 Using this xsl, I am getting only one Allowance per record(in the sample input, first allowance in the first record and first allowance in the second record). The expected output is  all the allowances in the first record and second record, as operation_code is same.`

```
  sample input: 
<root xmlns="">
<records>
    <record>
        <OPERATION_CODE>123456</OPERATION_CODE>
        <Combinations>
            <allowance>
                <WMI_CODE>MR0</WMI_CODE>
                <VDS_CODE>1</VDS_CODE>
            </allowance>    
            <allowance>
                <WMI_CODE>MR1</WMI_CODE>
                <VDS_CODE>2</VDS_CODE>
            </allowance>    
        </Combinations> 
        </record>
    <record>
        <OPERATION_CODE>123456</OPERATION_CODE>
        <Combinations>
            <allowance>
                <WMI_CODE>MR2</WMI_CODE>
                <VDS_CODE>3</VDS_CODE>
            </allowance>
        </Combinations> 
    </record>
    </records>
    </root>
```

expected output :

```
<LaborOperationsDetail>
    <LaborOperationID>123456</LaborOperationID>
    <Combinations>
        <Allowance>
            <GroupID>MR0</star:GroupID>
            <VID>1</star:VID>
        </Allowance>
        <Allowance>
            <GroupID>MR1</star:GroupID>
            <VID>2</star:VID>
        </Allowance>
        <Allowance>
            <GroupID>MR2</star:GroupID>
            <VID>3</star:VID>
        </Allowance>
    </Combinations>
<LaborOperationsDetail>
```

xsl used :

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="opcode" match="record" use="OPERATION_CODE" />
    <xsl:template match="root/records">
    <xsl:for-each select="record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('opcode', OPERATION_CODE)[1])]">
        <LaborOperationsDetail>
            <LaborOperationID><xsl:value-of select="OPERATION_CODE"/></LaborOperationID>
            <Combinations>           
            <xsl:for-each select="key('opcode' ,OPERATION_CODE)">
                 <Allowance>
                    <GroupID><xsl:value-of select="Combinations/allowance/WMI_CODE" /></GroupID>
                    <VID><xsl:value-of select="Combinations/allowance/VDS_CODE" /></VID>
                </Allowance>
            </xsl:for-each >
            </Combinations>  
        </LaborOperationsDetail>
    </xsl:for-each >
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please edit your input, expected output and stylesheet to be well-formed XML documents. Currently all three are not. -- Consider also reducing the example to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: I have edited the input. Kindly suggest some solution

Comment: Still not good: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/bFDb2BR

Comment: I have edited the input again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="opcode" match="record" use="OPERATION_CODE"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="records/record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('opcode', OPERATION_CODE)[1])]">
        <LaborOperationsDetail>
            <LaborOperationID>
                <xsl:value-of select="OPERATION_CODE"/>
            </LaborOperationID>
            <Combinations>           
                <xsl:for-each select="key('opcode' ,OPERATION_CODE)/Combinations/allowance">
                    <Allowance>
                        <GroupID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="WMI_CODE"/>
                        </GroupID>
                        <VID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="VDS_CODE"/>
                        </VID>
                    </Allowance>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Combinations>  
        </LaborOperationsDetail>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>     

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

What you have now:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('opcode' ,OPERATION_CODE)">
```

selects the two `record` nodes in the current group, and creates one `Allowance` node for each. Within these nodes, the values are retrieved from the **first** `allowance` in each `record`.